# How to convert DWORD to FILETIME in LUA?

Tags: lua

I am trying to read a file that has two `DWORD`s for the `FILETIME` (this is a prefetch file).

I read at offset 0x81 (0x80 + 1 because of 1-index in lua).  How do I go about taking the 8 bytes and converting into a filetime using only lua?

Starting at 0x80 in my hex editor, I have:

```
FB54B341B70CCf01
```

Needs to correlate to 01/08/2014

Comment: What code have you tried? In lua a string is just a sequence of bytes so you should be able to read every byte individually, then you just need how to decode them into the date. But this depends on how the filetime is encoded, it is not specific to Lua. How/where was this timestamp generated?

Comment: May be it can help https://github.com/moteus/lua-path/blob/master/lua/path/win32/fs.lua#L327-L336

Answer (score 1):

## What is FILETIME

The Windows platform [defines `FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be a 64-bit integer "count of 100ns intervals since January 1, 1601 UTC".

You will have at least two challenges with dealing with `FILETIME` in Lua.

First, it a `FILETIME` is a 64-bit integer and Lua stores numbers internally as IEEE double precision, which only supports 56 bits of precision. To the precision of the envelope I just scribbled on, you need more than 57 significant bits to name any time today as a `FILETIME`.

(Aside: I estimated that by noticing that there are about 1e7*pi seconds in a year, 1e7 100ns ticks in a second, and today is about 413 years after the `FILETIME` epoch. So dates in 2014 need about log2(413e14 * pi) bits, or a little more than 57 bits.)

Second, pure Lua doesn't have easy to use functions for converting binary data structures to and from native Lua data types. It isn't difficult to build such functions out of `string.byte()` and `string.sub()` and that is even safe to do since strings are 8-bit clean. But it is something you have to build yourself, or find from a third-party source.

But be aware that although there are binary structure libraries out there, many of them only provide limited support for 64-bit integers due to the limitations of Lua numbers. You may be better suited by a hand-crafted module in C that stores a `FILETIME` in a `userdata` and provides suitable operators to allow them to be compared, converted to and from a string, and so forth.

## Your Example

> Starting at 0x80 in my hex editor, I have:
>
> ```
> FB54B341B70CCf01
> ```
>
> Needs to correlate to 01/08/2014

Windows on a PC is a little-endian platform. That means that values are stored with the least-significant byte at the lowest address. So we can rewrite your sample timestamp to be more readable by reversing the bytes:

> 01CF0CB741B354FB

As expected, the 57'th bit is the most significant set bit, so this value is plausible for this century.